# Using Tab and Stack Navigator Together

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am building an App on React-Native for which I am using [React-Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/)

Now, Inside that i am using `Stack-Navigation` and  `TabNavigator` (updated it `DrawerNavigator`)

```
import { 
  createStackNavigator,
   TabNavigator,
   DrawerNavigator
 } from 'react-navigation';

import CoinCapCharts from "./src/container/CoinCapCharts.js"

import CoinCap from './src/container/CoinCap.js';


//THis is being Exported to App.js

 export const Tab = TabNavigator({
  TabA: {
    screen: CoinCap 
  },
  TabB: {
    screen: CoinCap
  }
}, {
  order: ['TabA', 'TabB'],
  animationEnabled: true,
})

export const MyScreen = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { 
    screen: CoinCap
  },
  CoinCapCharts: {
     screen: CoinCapCharts
    }
},{
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    headerMode: 'none'
});


export const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
  Tabs: { screen: Tab },
  Stack: { screen: MyScreen },
})
```

I am importing this in my App.js where I am doing something like this

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Drawer
 }from './Screen.js';
import {
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <View>
      <Drawer/>
      <Tab/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Now, This is indeed showing Tab the first time I run my app but after I navigate to different screen and return back, It doesn't appear to be showing that Tab again

**[Question:]** What could I be doing wrong and How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to define one within the other. 
Something like:

```
const Tab =  TabNavigator({
  TabA: {
    screen: Home 
  },
  TabB: {
    screen: Home
  }
}, {
  order: ['TabA', 'TabB'],
  animationEnabled: true,
})

export const MyStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { 
    screen: Home 
  },
  CoinCapCharts: {
     screen: CoinCapCharts
  },
  Tab: { 
    screen: Tab
  },
},{
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    headerMode: 'none'
});
```

Now, render MyStack (not sure that `Screen` is the best name :)

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <View>
      <MyStack />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Answer @Yossi. I tried your solution and while it doesn't throw any error, it isn't displaying that bottom Tab as well

Comment: Does it display the Home screen on startup? Does it display the Tab when you navigate to it?